# How to set icon for whole tab button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to set icon for whole tab button?

[image]

This code is download from the internet and The text the tab doesnt have to be there.
....
I apologize for the perfect English translation. The picture speaks for itself

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.likepress,
        R.drawable.kufrpress,
        R.drawable.referralpress,
        R.drawable.changepress
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "For");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you want it to take up the whole area - you may need to create your own custom XML element / Java class. Or, you could dig into the native element and attempt to resize the imageview, remove padding and margin. Just some thoughts...

Comment: Hello. I'm really a beginner, so tabwidget is easiest for me. Please adjust my code to add  custom XML element / Java class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabLayout.getTabAt(i)setCustomView(view)` to place a custom view for each tab. For example it can be an `ImageView` with your icon